I can't access a localhost Database (Mysql)
I have some problems trying to access a database in my localhost:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -u finanzas -h localhost -p
Enter password: ********
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)
It was working several minutes ago and I didn't do anything rare.

Your mysql stopped most likely if you get can't connect error messgage. Or mysql listens on a different port.

If you are using XAMPP, try "mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u USER -p"
